# Can I specify the OS-level build user on a per-job basis?

Tags: jenkins

Our team is sharing a Jenkins server with other teams, and this currently means that we are sharing the same OS-level build-user account.  The different teams' OS-level build-user settings (Maven settings, bash settings, user-level Ant libraries, etc...) have collided a few times--"fixing" the settings for one team's jobs inadvertently "breaks" another team's jobs.  The easiest sol'n that occurs to me is giving each team its own OS-level build-user account with which to execute its Jenkins jobs--but I cannot find a way to do this.

I have checked with Google, and also here

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins

and here

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins

to no avail.

Is there a way to do this?  If not, can you recommend any best practices for segregating sets of builds from one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maven Specific

You have two options that come to mind,

1. Add additional installations of Maven into your Jenkins global configuration, each using their own Home directory, and thus settings files. This will allow you to use totally different version of Maven, and selected based on Job requirements (You are given the option to select which "version" of maven you wish to use on the job itself.
2. Similar to (1), but specify specific settings configurations using Maven command line arguments. Its a little less "obvious" but may be quicker to implement

### Multi-slave

You could possibly make use of multiple slaves on each machine. It increases the overheads of the builds quite significantly, and the implementation is such that you'd have multiple user accounts on a machine, each setup as needed, and then one slave instance for each user.

I'm not sure these solutions will totally answer your problem, I'll have a think and see if anything else pops into mind, but it might give some starting points

Comment: I like the sound of your multi-slave sol'n, Toby.  I will give that a try and post an update.

Comment: @abluesongbird, have you tried this? If you did and it worked, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: The multi-slave solution works well.  We have two slaves running as different users on the same machine, and the jobs are segregated nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Key builds to a specific team directory that contains that team's settings. For example, provide a parameter 'TEAM' to every build, set its default value to the appropriate team name, and use that parameter as a key to a directory that contains the team's settings (so instead of using ${HOME} as in what you want to do, you'll use something like ${TEAM_SETTINGS}/${TEAM}).

Answer (score 0):

You can set per-job users (who has access to/can build a particular job).

Under "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" >

- Click on **Enable Security**
- Check **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy**

However, I do not think there is a "per-build" option for a single job.

If you have the same project that you are sharing between teams, you could (and probably should) create two jobs for this project, and have different libraries/scripts be used in each.

You could also parametrize the build (On the Job Page, "Configure" > **This build is parametrized**) and supply the library versions, etc via string parameters.

You could also use a parameter to be the team's name, and in your build script change libraries based on the parameter:

For example, have a parameter called "TEAM", with choices: TEAM_A and TEAM_B, and in your script, have

```
if [ $TEAM == "TEAM_A" ]
then
  ANT_HOME=/opt/ant/libA
else
  ANT_HOME=/opt/ant/libB
fi
```

**======================================================================**

Have you considered sourcing your settings? In Linux, you could do this by saving your OS settings in a script file (for example paths, etc), and using `source /path/to/settings/file`, in Windows it would be `call /path/to/settings/batch/file`.

Can you give examples of OS level settings that you would require and per-build user for?

Comment: Thanks, Sagar.  I see now that there were some ambiguities in my original question.  I have clarified them in the original question.

Comment: That makes it a little more complicated. Will edit my answer if I can think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is a common one.

Whenever something nonstandard is installed on a build server, something will break for someone.

The only solutions I know are

- Set up a separate build slave for each team or product. Then they can install whatever they want on the build slave and any mess they create is all their own fault.
- Any dependencies required by a job need to come with the job. This is my preferred way of working. For example: If a job needs a library or a tool, the library or tool is not installed on the build server but in the source tree and the build uses it from the source tree.

Sometimes the latter way is more work. You need to set up the tools or library so it works when it is installed in the source tree. Some tools have hard-coded paths and they do not work. In that case you can install the source of the tool and compile the tool during the build.

An even better solution is to set up separate Jenkins jobs for all the tools and libraries and the jobs that need a library or tool will download them from the Jenkins jobs.

This way you can control all your dependencies and different jobs do not conflict when e.g. one needs an older version of a library and one a newer version. And if someone upgrades the library, it is immediately visible in the version control who did what.